# Возможна ли HTML и JS валидация одновременно?

Tags: javascript, html, валидация

Стоит такая задача. Не спрашивайте ситуацию и зачем такой способ, просто в данном случае так надо.

Форма проходит валидацию html полей, их type.
JS выполняет мини-валидацию для кнопки отправки формы и сравнивает 2 поля. Надо, если 2 поля не равны, то не отправлять форму, но вывести ошибку валидации этой формы от html.

Я пробовал несколько вариантов:

1. Сделал form.submit();, но это не подошло, потому что не выполнялась html валидация формы, а форма просто не отправлялась. То есть 50% нужного результата.
2. Валидация полей проходила в Js, но даже если 2 поля отличаются, то js выдавал свою ошибку валидации, но всё равно отправлял форму.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы проходила JS и HTML валидация формы одновременно, но в случае ошибки в валидации JS, выводились результаты HTML валидации, но форма не отправлялась?

Надеюсь, не сильно запутал.
Спасибо!

Вот мой случай:

```js
function validate() {
  let a = document.forms["formId"]["name"].value;
  if (a == "") {
    return false;
  }
  let b = document.forms["formId"]["date"].value;
  if (b == "") {
    return false;
  }
  let c = document.forms["formId"]["dateend"].value;
  if (c == "") {
    return false;
  }
  if (new Date(b) >= new Date(c)) {
    document.forms["formId"]["date"].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(250, 10, 10, 0.3)";
    document.forms["formId"]["dateend"].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(250, 10, 10, 0.3)";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.forms["formId"]["date"].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(130, 130, 255, 0.1)";
    document.forms["formId"]["dateend"].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(130, 130, 255, 0.1)";
  }
  let d = document.forms["formId"]["description"].value;
  if (d == "") {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function funBut() {
  if (validate()) {
    var onebutn = document.getElementById("onebutn");
    var twobutn = document.getElementById("twobutn");
    onebutn.style.display = "none";
    twobutn.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formId" name="upload" action="scripts/generator.php" target="_blank" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <div style="width:auto;">
      <label for="email">Имя</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="200" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Дата начала</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" min="2020-01-01T00:00" max="5000-01-01T00:00" id="date" name="date" onChange="document.getElementById('dateend').min=this.value" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dateend">Дата окончания</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" min="2020-01-01T00:00" max="5000-01-01T00:00" id="dateend" name="dateend" style="color: white;" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width:auto;">
      <label for="description">Комментарий</label>
      <textarea id="description" name="description" maxlength="1500" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="twobutn" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group" id="bch">
        <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" style="color: white;" value="Проверить" onClick="document.upload.action='scripts/generator.php'; return true;">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="bby" style="width:auto;">
        <input type="submit" class='open-modal' id="create" name="create" value="Создать мероприятие">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="onebutn" class="form-group" style="width:auto;">
      <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" style="color: white;" value="Проверить" onClick="funBut(); document.upload.action='scripts/generator.php'; return true;">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: дайте пример, чтобы точно понять, что именно вы хотели сделать.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Добавил

Answer (score 1):

## Как с помощью JavaScript блокировать отправку формы?

- `<form onsubmit="return false" >`
  *внутри `onsubmit` вернуть `false`*
- `<form onsubmit="return validate(this)" >`
  *или вызвать функцию, которая вернёт `false`*

```js
/** @param {HTMLFormElement} el */
function validate(el = document.forms['Ffq']) {
    const { text, start, end } = validate.getVars(el)
    // -,-
    // console.log({ text, start, end })
    const isOK = [
        , !!text// можно убрать, т.к. `<input required>`
        , (new Date(start) <= new Date(end))
    ].every(q => true === q)
    if (isOK) return true;
    else return false;
}
/** @param {HTMLFormElement} el */
validate.getVars = function getVars(el) {
    const { value: text } = el['text'];
    const { value: start } = el['start'];
    const { value: end } = el['end'];
    // -,-
    return { text, start, end, }
}
```

```html
<script>
  // ----> перехватчик исключительно для демонстрации работы кода
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
    // - ,- catch
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    // -, -
    console.group('beforeunload')
    formData = new FormData(document.forms['Ffq']);
    console.dir(JSON.stringify([...formData]))
    console.groupEnd()
  })
  // <----
</script>
<form name="Ffq" method="post" action="https://localhost" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
  <input type="text" name="text" required>
  <input type="date" name="start">
  <input type="date" name="end">
</form>
```

### список "полезной литературы"

- HTML тег `<form>` - http://htmlbook.ru/html/form
- отправка формы средствами JavaScript - https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms
- `FormData` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData
- `document.forms` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

Comment: А можно пример конкретно под мой случай?

Comment: в вашем случае нужно ещё избавиться от всех `onClick`

Comment: Убрать их все нельзя, мне нужно менять action в зависимости от нажатой кнопки

Comment: И Ваш пример только с одним полем. Привидите пример хотя-бы с двумя полями

Comment: И мне кажется, что Ваш вариант не обрабатывает html валидацию

Answer (score 0):

что же касается кода, приведённого автором вопроса:

### переработанный JS + теория из предыдущего(общего) ответа

обоснования своих изысканий с доказательством на примере кода автора вопроса

```js
function funBut() {
    const isValid = validate()
    if (isValid) {
        document.getElementById("onebutn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("twobutn").style.display = "block";
    }
    // console.log({ isValid })
    return isValid
}
/** @param {HTMLFormElement} _formId */
function validate(_formId = document.forms['formId']) {
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement[]} */
    const els = ['name', 'date', 'dateend', 'description'].map(q => _formId[q])
    const [_name, _date, _dateend, _description] = els
    const [a, b, c, d] = els.map(el => el.value)
    // -,-
    const dd = (new Date(b) >= new Date(c))
    // -,-
    if (dd) [_date, _dateend].forEach(validate.styleErr)
    else[_date, _dateend].forEach(validate.styleOk)
    if ([a, b, c, d].every(q => "" != q) && dd) return false;
    return true;
}
validate.styleErr = style({ backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 10, 10, 0.3)' })
validate.styleOk = style({ backgroundColor: 'rgba(130, 130, 255, 0.1)' })
/** @param {CSSStyleDeclaration} style */
function style(style) {
    /** @param {HTMLElement} el */
    const f = el => { Object.assign(el.style, style) }
    return f
}
```

```html
<script>// ---- > перехватчик исключительно для демонстрации работы кода
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",o=>{o.preventDefault(),o.stopPropagation(),console.group("beforeunload"),formData=new FormData(document.forms.formId),console.dir(JSON.stringify([...formData])),console.groupEnd()});
// <----</script>

<hr>
2020-01-01T00:00<br>
5000-01-01T00:00<br>
<hr>

<form id="formId" name="upload" action="http://localhost" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return funBut();">
  <div>
    <div style="width:auto;">
      <label for="email">Имя</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="200" required value="имя" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Дата начала</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" min="2020-01-01T00:00" max="5000-01-01T00:00" id="date" name="date" onChange="document.getElementById('dateend').min=this.value" required value="2020-01-01T00:00" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dateend">Дата окончания</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" min="2020-01-01T00:00" max="5000-01-01T00:00" id="dateend" name="dateend" style="color: white;" required value="5000-01-01T00:00" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width:auto;">
      <label for="description">Комментарий</label>
      <textarea id="description" name="description" maxlength="1500" required>коммент</textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="twobutn" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group" id="bch">
        <input type="button" id="check" name="check" style="color: white;" value="Проверить 2" onclick="funBut();">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" id="bby" style="width:auto;">
        <input type="submit" class='open-modal' id="create" name="create" value="Создать мероприятие">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="onebutn" class="form-group" style="width:auto;">
      <input type="button" id="check" name="check" style="color: white;" value="Проверить 1" onclick="funBut(); ">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

### комментарии/замечания

#### `onClick`

похоже на реакт. `style` же - строчный. хмм.

я не утверждаю, просто оставлю это тут:

- https://validator.w3.org/

#### `<input type="submit"/>`

Должен быть один. Отстальные - `<input type="button"/>`

Добавим к ним по проверке-подсветке-экшнпереключалке `onclick="funBut();"`

#### `<form onsubmit="return funBut();">`

Это ключевая часть, отвечает за то - будет ли отправлена форма или нет. (см. предыдущий ответ)

#### использование различного синтаксиса

в одном месте используется `document.upload`
в другом - `document.forms['formId']`

Comment: Запустил Ваш код здесь на стаке. Что в итоге: код выделяет ошибочные поля, но вторая кнопка всё равно появляется и форма отправляется и ошибок валидации html нет

Comment: @Дмитрий, это просьба или предъява?

Comment: Это комментарий

Comment: А мне показалось вам что-то нужно. Ок. В следующем вопросе указывайте браузер.